# jqgrid page navigation and page count is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

i have a problem with jqgrid .in that pagecount displaying 0 and page navaigation not working.. here i have attached all related code.

Grid Data is displaying but pagecount and pagination from one page to another page is not working.. i have attached image also which was coming output for me.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: '/Home/EmpList', 
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    width: 970,
    height: 290,

    mtype: 'GET',
   colNames: ['Part#', 'Description', 'Application', 'Category', 'Points/$','Valid  
  Untill'],
   colModel: [{ name: 'part_number', index: 'part_number', width: 180 },
               { name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 220 },
               { name: 'pplication', index: 'application', width: 220 },
               { name: 'category', index: 'category', width: 180 },
               { name: 'point_dollar', index: 'point_dollar', width: 180 },
                { name: 'end_date', index: 'end_date', width: 180 }
              ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: 'part_number',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    //viewpages: true,
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    gridComplete: function () {
    }
   });
  });
```

**cshtml**

```
   <link href="~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
   <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Parts.js"></script>

  <table id="grid" style=" width:970px;"></table>
                <table id="pager">
```

**controller class**

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult EmpList()
    {   
        List<Parts> obs = new List<Parts>();
        string   
    cs=Sytem.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BMWRewards"].  
     ConnectionString.ToString();
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "[admin].[usp_parts_list_get]";
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oem_id", 2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "IRF");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", "ALL");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "");
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Parts obl = new Parts();
                obl.part_number=reader["part_number"].ToString();
                obl.description=reader["description"].ToString();
                obl.application=reader["application"].ToString();
                obl.category=reader["part_category_name"].ToString();
                obl.point_dollar=float.Parse(reader["point_dollar"].ToString());
                obl.end_date=reader["end_date"].ToString();
                obs.Add(obl);
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        if (obs.Count() > 0)
        {
            var pageData = obs;
            var jsonData = new
            {   
                total = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)pageData.FirstOrDefault().RowCount /  
               (float)10),
                page = pageData.FirstOrDefault().PageNumber,
                records = pageData.FirstOrDefault().PageSize,
                rows =
                (from rdata in pageData
                 select new
                 {
                     i = rdata.part_number,
                     cell = new string[] { (rdata.part_number).ToString(),
                   rdata.description, rdata.application, 

                  rdata.category,rdata.point_dollar.ToString(),rdata.end_date }
                 }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            var jsonData1 = new
            {
                total = 0,
                page = 1,
                records = 0
            };
            return Json(jsonData1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to try to use string like `"0"` instead of integer value for `total`, `page` and `records` properties at least in case of `obs.Count() == 0`:

```cs
var jsonData1 = new
{
    total = "0",
    page = "1",
    records = "0"
};
return Json(jsonData1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```